# Why are comments not included in question-feeds?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I like to monitor the development of a question in which I'm involved in an RSS-reader. Often the interesting development is in the comments, though. Currently, a question's RSS feed includes only the question and any answers that are given.

**Q:** Why are the comments not included in the feeds?

Answer (score 3):

Comments are viewed as third-class citizens in Stack Exchange, as little "post-it notes" attached to the post. That is, truly *significant* information should be edited into the body of the post, not buried in a comment somewhere.

We've also been de-emphasizing RSS, meaning we probably won't be changing or improving the current level of RSS support for the forseeable future.

Combining those two factors, it's not likely to be supported any time soon.